What are the standards for mandatory review by the US supreme court?
According to my MBE Critical pass flashcards (flashcard #6 in the Constitutional Law category titled "supreme court jurisdiction and review"):

Methods of Supreme Court review:

discretionary review - most cases get to the Supreme Court by writ of certiorari; the Court then decides whether to grant review
mandatory review - the court must take appeals from three-judge district court panels regarding injunctive relief (this bypasses the courts of appeal).


I cannot figure out what the bolded portion (my emphasis) means or refers to. What does it mean and what is the legal theory/reasoning behind this? Why the exception? Why would there even be a three-judge district court panel regarding injunctive relief anyway?
Note: by Supreme Court I am referring to the US Supreme Court.

This started in the Three-Judge Court Act of June 18, 1910 dealing with injunctive relief against unconstitutional State legislation.  The aim of three judges was to reduce inappropriate injunctions; the aim of direct appeal was to promote swifter resolution. https://scholarship.law.uc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1415&context=fac_pubs may be of interest

Three judge district court panels with no intermediate appellate court review arise primarily under the Voting Rights Act for challenges to state election administration laws. There may be other examples of it, but this is the predominant one. This arises by statute.

In case it isn't obvious to some readers, I would note that "this arises by statute" is a response to "what is the legal theory behind this?"  For the most part, avenues for appeal in the US are specified by statute.

Not sure if this is what the OP was (also) thinking, but can something be said as to what power enables Congress to mandate SCOTUS take up an appeal?  Most of SCOTUS is, to quip, "we do what we want, when we want, how we want, because we declare separation of powers!" So what's the mechanism by which congress can mandate an appeal be taken up? I see they have the power to modify their appellate jurisdiction, but is it just an ancient aspect of common law that this includes non-discretionary mandates to take up an appeal, or something else?

@zibadawatimmy The appeal is non-discretionary by virtual of the procedural provisions of the Voting Rights Act.

@ohwilleke Well, sure, but Congress could just as well pass a law saying that people named Bob aren't allowed to talk about sandwiches, but they lack the constitutional authority and power to do so validly under the 1st amendment. What is the constitutional power and authority through which this law and its procedural provisions validly creates a mandatory action by SCOTUS? As opposed to just declaring it with no actual basis, with SCOTUS taking them ultimately only because they want to every time, and are clearly granted power to do so, rather than because they have no say in the matter.

@zibadawatimmy "What is the constitutional power and authority through which this law and its procedural provisions validly creates a mandatory action by SCOTUS?" See Art. III, § 2 "In all the other Cases before mentioned, the supreme Court shall have appellate Jurisdiction, both as to Law and Fact, with such Exceptions, and under such Regulations as the Congress shall make." See also e.g., Art I, § 4 (election regulations) and § 8 ("To make all Laws which shall be necessary and proper . . . ") and the enforcement sections of Amendment 13-15, 19, 24, and 26.

@ohwilleke I take it the key phrase here is "under such regulations...", where prescribing that taking up the appeal is mandatory is a regulation (of their appellate jurisdiction)? With the rest mostly making it clear that they have authority to pass legislation which can then have its appellate jurisdiction for SCOTUS and other courts regulated?

@zibadawatimmy Pretty much.
